# Customer review dataset

Tags: data-request, nlp

I would like to get customer review data set like amazon customer review data.

I would like to have rather unique review data instead of amazon review data, 
because amazon data sets have been heavily used by many papers already.

I am even thinking of purchasing data and wonder if there is any company 
where I can purchase quality review data.

Comment: Purchased data aren't Open Data and a study based on purchased and non-sharable data suffers from being irreproducible.

Comment: Following @jknappen's comment, if you want unique data, then open data certainly isn't what you want.