# Customer review dataset that can be publicly reshareable

Tags: data-request, nlp

I'm looking for a dataset of customer reviews and whose license allows academic and industry researchers to annotate the dataset and publicly share the annotated dataset (e.g., via a GitHub repo).

I found [Customer review dataset](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7510/1652) but in my case I don't wish to pay for the dataset, and it has to be publicly reshareable.

Comment: I am still interested in such a dataset.

Comment: Any pointer is welcome.